# PyQt5 Getters and Setters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In an attempt to tech myself a method for binding in python, I have the following code:

```
wname = QLineEdit()
dname = "Test Value"
sattr  = getattr(wname, "text")
```

**How to assign the value of dname to wname using the info from above?**

I do understand that setText() would typically be used here; however, I am exploring a method for binding and I would like to know how to utilitze the `getattr()` function for extracting the setter and getter for the widget passed.  Thanks!!!

Comment: `setattr(wname, 'text', dname)` or `getattr(wname, 'setText')(dname)`. The former only really makes sense if the attribute is a [qt property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#properties).

Comment: pyqt is written in C++, it does not use [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), so getting the getter and the setter will not be possible as you think, as ekhumoro points out, something close to what you want is to use q-properties

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified that I will be using Qt widgets for my binding.

Comment: @Elcid_91 that does not change anything, the Qt Widgets are QObject that you also have the q-properties

Comment: @Elcid_91 A possible option is that you inherit the widgets and establish those properties.

Comment: The Qt equivalent to Python's object introspection is the [Meta-Object System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html). This allows you to retrieve a [QMetaProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaproperty.html) object for attributes defined with `Q_PROPERTY`. PyQt also supports  [defining new properties](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html#defining-new-qt-properties) using the `pyqtProperty` decorator. There is also the [pyqtConfigure](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html?highlight=pyqtconfigure) method, which can be used to set multiple qt properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the point, but by doing

```
sattr = getattr(wname, "text")
```

you are retrieving the function and not the text inside it. Therefore by calling

```
sattr("abc")
```

you will set the text. Same for writing:

```
sattr = gettar(wname, "setText")
sattr("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to receive the function, then utilize the retrieved function to set the value.  There will be different widgets and I need to retrieve their individual setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what Alessandro said, you need to get the setter with `getattr` first, then call it with your text:

```
wname = QLineEdit()
dname = "Test Value"
sattr = getattr(wname, "setText")
sattr(dname)
```

If you want to build some code that gets both the getters and setters based on a property name, I guess you could do something like this:

```
def get_getters_and_setters(widget, name):
    return getattr(widget, name), getattr(widget, 'set' + name[0].upper() + name[1:]
```

If, instead, you want something similar to the way `getattr` and `setattr` work with Python attributes but for already existing widget properties, I guess you could do something like the following, but it seems a bit of an overkill to me:

```
class CustomLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    @property
    def textAttribute(self):
        return self.text()

    @textAttribute.setter
    def textAttribute(self, value):
        self.setText(value)

wname = CustomLineEdit()
dname = "Test Value"
setattr(wname, 'textAttribute', dname)
```